# PHPExcel - How to read excel sheet with sheet id

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for import data from excel file.

In my current code I am reading sheet data with sheet name and getting results in array. Now I want to read sheet data with sheet id with bellow function.

`$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)`

but this is not working with my code.

**Here is my code work:**

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'hello.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'Sample'; // I DON'T WANT TO USE SHEET NAME HERE

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
echo ' Highest Column '. $getHighestColumn = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestColumn(); // Get Highest Column
echo ' Get Highest Row '. $getHighestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestRow(); // Get Highest Row

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($sheetData);
echo "</pre>";
```

**For Mark Baker:**

I am getting this result in my question code when sheet name is **Sample (Sheet ID: 2)**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => OrderDate
            [B] => Region
            [C] => Rep
            [D] => Item
            [E] => Units
            [F] => Unit Cost
            [G] => Total
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1/6/13
            [B] => East
            [C] => Jones
            [D] => Pencil
            [E] => 95
            [F] => 1.99
            [G] => 189.05
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1/23/13
            [B] => Central
            [C] => Kivell
            [D] => Binder
            [E] => 50
            [F] => 19.99
            [G] => 999.5
        )
```

After changing I am getting this result:

```
PHPExcel Object
(
    [_uniqueID:PHPExcel:private] => 543b9dab3f6da
    [_properties:PHPExcel:private] => PHPExcel_DocumentProperties Object
        (
            [_creator:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => comp-30
            [_lastModifiedBy:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_created:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 1158364800
            [_modified:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 1413191554
            [_title:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_description:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_subject:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_keywords:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_category:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_manager:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => 
            [_company:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => Microsoft Corporation
            [_customProperties:PHPExcel_DocumentProperties:private] => Array
                (
                    [KSOProductBuildVer] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1033-9.1.0.4674
                            [type] => s
                        )

                )

        )

    [_security:PHPExcel:private] => PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity Object
        (
            [_lockRevision:PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity:private] => 
            [_lockStructure:PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity:private] => 
            [_lockWindows:PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity:private] => 
            [_revisionsPassword:PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity:private] => 
            [_workbookPassword:PHPExcel_DocumentSecurity:private] => 
        )

    [_workSheetCollection:PHPExcel:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => PHPExcel_Worksheet Object
```

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, After editing your question, you've loaded the PHPExcel object with the worksheet that you want, then var_dumped the PHPExcel object..... use the PHPExcel methods like the worksheet's toArray() method, as you were using it before (e.g. `$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After help of `Mark Baker` Now I am able to get sheet data with sheet ID.

**Here is full code work:**

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'hello.xlsx';
$sheetIndex = 2;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$sheetnames = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames[$sheetIndex]);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($sheetData);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Thanks Mark Baker :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to load all the worksheets in the workbook, then change

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'hello.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'Sample'; // I DON'T WANT TO USE SHEET NAME HERE

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

to

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'hello.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'hello.xlsx';
$sheetIndex = 2;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$sheetnames = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames[$sheetIndex]);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

This will get the sheetname used for the sheet at sheetindex 2, and then use that sheetname to load only that sheet

Comment: I want to load specific sheet with sheet id. Result must be in array. Any Idea?

Comment: Current code working perfect for me but I don't want to use sheet name because when user change sheet name all logic crashed.

Comment: You can only load specific sheets by name, but you can execute a call  to `listWorksheetNames()` before loading the file to get a list of worksheet names.

Comment: Can you please provide me with code with explanation because I am getting some worng data in array. I will thankful if you support me :)

Comment: Explain what you mean by `worng data in array`.... I can't see what data you're getting, don't know what you expect to get, and can't see your spreadsheet file